# Is it possible to correlate specific ID using Loadrunner?

Tags: performance, testing, automation, correlation, loadrunner

{"Id":11911618,"LatestAsAtYear":2022,"ParentGroupId":22022,"NoOfBorrowingEntities":4,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntities":1,"SensitivityAccessibility":false,"CustomerGroupTotalLimit":104500001.00,"OPEXPerGroup":165760.00,"OverrideReason":null,"GroupStatusId":0,"GroupSimStatus":"Baseline","CreatedDateTime":"/Date(1675945044793)/","CreatedBy":"System","ModifiedDateTime":"/Date(1675945044793)/","ModifiedBy":"System","AssessedDateTime":"/Date(1675945044793)/","AssessedBy":"System","ApprovedDate":null,"ApprovedBy":null,"Currency":1,"CurrencyName":"MYR","NoOfBorrowingEntity":4,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntity":1,"ARMName":"SYSTEM","ARMAvatarFileId":null,"WithAllRollUpCusSim":true,"Justification":null,"hasOutdatedCusSim":false},

{"Id":**12238948**,"LatestAsAtYear":2022,"ParentGroupId":22022,"NoOfBorrowingEntities":5,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntities":16,"SensitivityAccessibility":false,"CustomerGroupTotalLimit":440772000.00,"OPEXPerGroup":301516.00,"OverrideReason":null,"GroupStatusId":1,"GroupSimStatus":"**Draft**","CreatedDateTime":"/Date(1677812701377)/","CreatedBy":"406038","ModifiedDateTime":"/Date(1677812701377)/","ModifiedBy":"406038","AssessedDateTime":"/Date(1677812701377)/","AssessedBy":"406038","ApprovedDate":null,"ApprovedBy":null,"Currency":1,"CurrencyName":"MYR","NoOfBorrowingEntity":5,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntity":16,"ARMName":"Loh Hui Joo","ARMAvatarFileId":null,"WithAllRollUpCusSim":true,"Justification":null,"hasOutdatedCusSim":false},

{"Id":12238947,"LatestAsAtYear":2022,"ParentGroupId":22022,"NoOfBorrowingEntities":1,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntities":0,"SensitivityAccessibility":false,"CustomerGroupTotalLimit":100000.00,"OPEXPerGroup":22636.00,"OverrideReason":null,"GroupStatusId":3,"GroupSimStatus":"Completed","CreatedDateTime":"/Date(1677811177550)/","CreatedBy":"406038","ModifiedDateTime":"/Date(1677811192897)/","ModifiedBy":"173660","AssessedDateTime":"/Date(1677811177550)/","AssessedBy":"406038","ApprovedDate":"/Date(1677811192897)/","ApprovedBy":"173660","Currency":1,"CurrencyName":"MYR","NoOfBorrowingEntity":1,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntity":0,"ARMName":"Loh Hui Joo","ARMAvatarFileId":null,"WithAllRollUpCusSim":true,"Justification":null,"hasOutdatedCusSim":false}]}

I am expecting to capture the ID specifically with the Draft staus

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
LB="{\"Id\":",
RB=",\"GroupSimStatus\":\"Draft"
ORD=ALL,
...
```

This leaves you with a string of

> **12238948**,"LatestAsAtYear":2022,"ParentGroupId":22022,"NoOfBorrowingEntities":5,"NoOfNonBorrowingEntities":16,"SensitivityAccessibility":false,"CustomerGroupTotalLimit":440772000.00,"OPEXPerGroup":301516.00,"OverrideReason":null,"GroupStatusId":1

Use your string processing skills in the language of your virtual user to break out the first set of characters up to the first comma and save that to a new variable using **lr_save_string()**

The above *assumes* that the ID will eventually grow beyond eight characters in length.

If you find that your string you wish to capture has a consistent, non-variable, length, then you should investigate the flags for **SaveOffset** and **SaveLen** to capture a subset of eight characters at the front of the correlation region without having to use your additional programming skills to break apart a string

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your answer - have tried and below my correlation have worked

 web_reg_save_param_ex(
  "ParamName=groupSimId",
  "LB=\"Id\":",
  "RB=\"GroupSimStatus\":\"Draft\"",
  "SaveLen=8",
  LAST);

Much appreciated